# Atlassian Application Links Inside Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, jira, confluence

I have problems with this specific container configuration and make the Atlassian tools use their Application Links flawlessly.

I have some atlassian applications running inside docker containers: Jira, Confluence, Crowd

All container are on the same server behind nginx:

- Nginx
- -> Confluence
- -> Jira
- -> Crowd

I access the container over nginx https proxy with the following subdomains:

- https://confluence.example.com
- https://jira.example.com
- https://crowd.example.com

How do I have to set up the Docker network or network in order that Jira can access Confluence with the URL https://confluence.example.com and Confluence can access Jira with the URL https://jira.example.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First I had to allow the Docker Bridge for my Docker Network to route traffic to the host. This is a bit cumbersome as the id for the network bridge for my Docker network is generated by Docker. I had to manually add a rule to iptables.
2. I am using letsencrypt server certificates and the letsencrypt ca is not part of the default java truststore. There for I had to add it to the following truststore: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.
3. Works!